# Stacking of video controls and div:hover elements?

Tags: css, html, video, z-index, mediaelement.js

I am trying to have video controls show up on top of my div container for another panel.

[image]

The control panel has the following CSS:

```
.panel-container{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 140px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0;
    &:hover {
      @include transition-delay(0s, 0s);
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

The video controls have the following CSS:

```
.mejs-controls {
    z-index: 100;
  }
```

However no matter the z-index, the video controls are not clickable.
What can be done to make the video controls appear on top of the panel-container (and the panel-container needs to be above the video itself).

Comment: Have you found any solution? I'm in the same position!